# Chrome Extension: Capturing HTML of every visited page in particular domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to store every visited page (just HTML) in a predefined domain. This is what I have so far:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML(tabId: tab.id, function(details){
    console.log("Page Content: " + details);
  });
}, {
  url: [{
    // Runs on my.com, my.co.uk, but also my.foo.com\
    hostContains: '.my.'
  }],
});
```

I am getting an error called:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Pointing to my chrome.pageCapture line. Not seeing it...

Comment: Replace `tabId: tab.id` with `tab.id`.

Comment: Ok, now it is error-free. However,  I do not see the console.log in the inspection window (with the content as shown here, but also not when only displaying a simple message). Are there reasons why it would not execute the saveAsMHTML method?

Comment: Uhm instead of tab.id use details.tabId. Always check the documentation for the exact syntax and parameters.